# API GOOGLE MAP V3

Tags: google-maps-v3

Estoy en medio de un problema, del que espero alguien me pueda tirar una idea. El caso es que debo abrir una ventana emergente, la cual debo llamarla desde en cuadro que abre infowindow. A continuacion les muestro el codigo con el cual puedo abrir una pagina, pero en mi caso no me sirve, lo que debo abrir es un popup. He intentado de varias forma, pero ya estoy en un punto donde creo que el arbol no me deja ver el bosque.

```
          var contentString = '<div id="div_cliente">'+
          '<b>'+cliente+'</b><br/>' +
          rubro+'<br/>' +
          '<b>'+titular+'</b><br/>' +
          RUC+'<br/>' +
          '<b>'+tele+'</b><br/>' +
          tari+'<br/>' +
          '<b>'+deuda+'</b><br/>' +

           '<p>Prueba llamada, <a href="prueba_ventana.php?valor=111111">'+'Click aqui</a>' + '</p>'+
          '</div>';
```

Esto funciona, pero como comente anteriormente lo que necesito es abrir un popup, no abrir una nueva pagina.

Desde ya, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

No indicas el código completo, pero lo que debes de hacer es crear un div en la web, posicionarlo como quieras mediante CSS y tal vez un poco de JavaScript para ponerlo donde ha pulsado el usuario.

Por otra parte tamibién mediante JavaScript establecer el contenido de dicho div con el que has indicado en el código.

Añade por ejemplo al final del html de tu web:

```
<div id='popup'></div>
```

Y en el evento que deberá pulsar el usuario dentro del infoWindow donde generas el contentString ejecutar este JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById('popup').innerHTML( contentString );
```

También pudes buscar y utilizar multitud de librerías para hacer dichas popups, con animaciones, lightboxes (oscurecer el fondo debajo del popup), etc, etc.